# What is best secure and anonymous Web Server for hosting Tor hidden services?

Tags: security

What is best secure and anonymous Web Server for hosting Tor hidden services?

and how can i remove any information about my Web Server and my Server OS that can be leaked ?

what is tor recommendation  about web server software and server os hosting ?

Answer (score 1):

how much you make it secure, that's how much it will be secured. it means, you will have to pay administrator to do it. it can be nginx or any other, just not apache.

you protect server with installing virtual machine and making hidden service inside VM, in that way attacker can attack VM but not host machine. so, host machine can be debian, for example.

beside it, you must choose hosting company, if you make mistake at that point, they can betray you or steal info about your users. and don't choose VPS, pay with btc and only at anonymous reg hosting companies, and so on and so on... you have my email.

Comment: thanks you, Is it necessary to used VPS ?

Comment: No, berkman is saying not to use VPS. He's saying to run the web server in a VM that's running on your hosted server. You run the Tor client on the host, or in another VM. That way, the web server cannot see the Internet except through Tor, even if it gets totally compromised. I still like thttpd as a web server, but it's no longer in the Debian repository. Nginx is arguably most secure, but lighttpd is OK, and easier to set up.

Comment: i would **NOT recommend BTC for anonymous payment** because BTC is just pseudonymous! so you have to consider a ton of things and be very careful to make it (hopefully) work anonymous. - i would rather advise to **use privacy coins like Monero (XMR)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try torpanda.com. They don't require any user information and they're hosted off shore in romania. They work with you on pretty much any payment method you want as long as it works too. I'm not sure what their security looks like, but I'm pretty sure you could ask. It seems to me that even if they did get hacked there's nothing to give you up anyways.